# How to work on pagination for multiple search results using MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, search-engine, information-retrieval

I'm working on a Web Search Engine project. I am working on the pagination feature. When I click on the page, it gives abrupt results and `Undefined variable: page1 error` is given. What to do?

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) //results displayed based on page selection
    {
    $page=$_GET['page'];
    if($page=="" || $page=="1")
    {
        $page1=0;
    }
    else
    {
    $page1=($page*10)-10;
    }
    }

$numrows1 = mysqli_num_rows($query); // page evaluation and this statement calculates number of resultant rows
$a = $numrows1/10; //10 is for number of results per page and $a gives number of pages
$a = ceil($a);
echo "<br>"; echo "<br>";
    for($b=1; $b<=$a; $b++)
    {
        ?><a href="search.php?page=<?php echo $b; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $b."  ";?></a><?php
    }
```

I hope I'm clear. Anyone can help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to never set the page unless you have a page in the URI.

I'm assuming if you used "page.php?page=1" it wouldn't throw that error since $page1 would be set.

I would personally do this:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != 1)//if page is set and page doesn't equal 1
{
    $startingRecord = ($_GET['page'] * 10) - 10;
}
else
{
    $startingRecord = 0;
}
```

Also, I switched `$page1` to be `$startingRecord` to make more sense, as you are calculating the starting record, not the page.